# Intellij doesn't recognize resource bundles

Tags: intellij-idea, resourcebundle

IntelliJ comes with a [resource bundle editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/editing-resource-bundle.html) but I can't use it.

I have this file structure in my project but the "resources" folder doesn't seem to be recognized as a "resource bundle". What's wrong?

[image: Resource files in my project]

Answer (score 2):

Your properties files must follow specific naming conventions to be recognized as resource bundles. Look [at this JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) for more details.

**TLDR**: Rename your files to `languages_en.properties`, `languages_es.properties` and so on it should work (notice the underscore instead of dash).